# Predicting regression tree using rpart (iris dataset)

Tags: r, rstudio, regression

IRIS DATSET

```
dt3 = rpart(Species ~., control = rpart.control( minsplit = 10, maxdepth = 5),data=iris , method = "poisson")  

dt3 [contents obtained from dt3][2]
```

and the plot is as shown.

IRIS DATASET Regression Tree Plot
[image]

[image]

So my question is, what are the parameters in specific boxes `what is 2 ; 300 / 150 and 100% in root node` while using regression tree?
Please help me with the solution.

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your question.

Comment: Suggested edits are done thanks to all. Answer please.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you decided to use poisson distribution with the data, If you don't pass method parameter, it will generate this graph -

[image]

As per rpart.plot documentation (that you use and didn't mention!) -

```
Each node shows
- the predicted class
- the predicted probability of each class,
- the percentage of observations in the node.
```

So in first node, majority class in setosa, each class has 33% probability, and 100% of observations are used. Similarly in green node, majority class is virginica, 98% of data belongs to virginica, and 31% of observations are present in this node.

Please google before posting here and refer to documentation. Plus always give code you used with data.

Comment: As i am very new to stack overflow i will improve all your suggested edits and will sure give the codes from next on-wards. Thanks a lot for your answer. MANY MANY THANKS